# How to count every time values in two columns are both NOT NA?

Tags: r

Let's say that I am working with data from soccer players. I have players' names, and countries that they have played in, and how many goals they've scored in these respective countries.

```
  players England USA Brazil
1     ben       0   3    NA
2    josh       3   0     2
3    mike       3   0     4
4     sam       0   3     3
5    luis      NA   1    NA
6    john       1   NA    1
7    javi       NA  NA    3
8   terry       1   1     NA
```

I would like to compare every pair of columns. So what I would like here is three numbers: the number of times there are two numbers in a row for the England, USA columns (5 here), the number of times there are two numbers in a row for USA, Brazil (3 here), and the number of times there are two numbers in the England, Brazil Columns (4 here).

- I edited the question after a comment made me realize that posting the question with only two columns reduced the problem too much.

Comment: @goldisfine Do you want to compare every pair of columns?

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was not clear, @akrun

Comment: I normally downvote when they completely change the question without notifying the answerers.  But it's Friday and Halloween :)

Comment: What is the best way to notify the answers such that they see it? Thanks for not downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use

```
sum(!rowSums(is.na(df[,-1])))
#[1] 5
```

#### Update

Based on the new dataset

```
 indx <- combn(colnames(df)[-1],2)
 res <- sapply(split(indx, col(indx)), function(x) 
                          sum(!rowSums(is.na(df[,x]))))

 names(res) <- apply(indx,2, paste, collapse="_")
 res
 # England_USA England_Brazil     USA_Brazil 
 #        5              4              3
```

A shorter code (as suggested by @Ananda Mahto) would be:

```
 unlist(combn(df[-1], 2, function(x) 
            setNames(sum(complete.cases(x)), 
            paste(names(x), collapse = "-")), simplify = FALSE))

# England-USA England-Brazil     USA-Brazil 
#         5              4              3
```

Comment: I was going to post `unlist(combn(mydf[-1], 2, function(x) setNames(sum(complete.cases(x)), paste(names(x), collapse = "-")), simplify = FALSE))`.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto That looks better.

Answer (score 0):

Use is.na with and...

```
txt<-'players England USA
1     ben       0   3
2    josh       3   0
3    mike       3   0
4     sam       0   3
5    luis      NA   1
6    john       1   NA
7    javi       NA  NA
8   terry       1   1 '

df<-read.table(text=txt)

bothNArows <- which(is.na(df$England) & is.na(df$USA))
(nbad<-length(bothNArows))
```